# iFuse to access iPhone files on Windows

Tags: windows, fuse

Trying to use [iFuse](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse) to access iPhone files on Windows but not getting anyway. Would appreciate if people can share instructions/steps on how to get this to work?

iFuse to access iPhone files on Ubuntu works well; therefore, I am confident the issue is on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/hooby3dfx/ifuse/releases/tag/win-dokany-0.1

- Unzip test.zip in the above link
- make sure iTune is installed
- Install the specified Dokan version; doesn't seem to work with the latest Dokan version
- Open a command window in Admin mode to run the command (e.g. ifuse tmnt --container *bundle ID*)
- While the command is still running in the Admin window, open another command window to list the mounted directory